# Issues using run-ios with React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, mobile

It seems that once every other week I have the same issue where my React Native project stops building and won't open in Xcode, and I wanted to know what some fixes could be for this. When I try and build in Visual Studio Code the app gets stuck at the `⠇ Building the app` message. And when I try opening the workspace in Xcode, Xcode stops responding and it gets stuck on the spinning rainbow wheel. For some reason, `npx react-native start` works just fine, the issue occurs when using `npx react-native run-ios`.

When this happens it takes me hours to troubleshoot and I can't find a consistent fix for this issue. Does anyone have experience with this and know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue results from Xcode's way of handling iCloud files. I was able to resolve the issue by moving my project to a folder that is not in my iCloud Drive.